# Jquery clear event for .one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bottom code. When I click on edit button, I would like to clear the event that is on below m-state class.

```
$('.m-state').one('click', function() {
    #code...
});

$('.edit').click(function(evt) {
    # clear m-state class event.
})
```

How to I unbind event when I click on edit button? I tried to use .off and unbind, but they didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to get off to work: http://jsfiddle.net/k4aoggmp/

```
<div class="test1">Test 1</div>
<div class="test2">Test 2</div>
```

.

```
var oneHandler = function() { alert('yo'); };
$('.test1').one('click', oneHandler);

$('.test2').on('click', function(evt) {
    $('.test1').off('click', oneHandler);
})
```